# Do all AJAX requests in Ember.js need to be cast into Ember.RSVP.Promise?

Tags: ember.js

If I make an AJAX request in Ember:

```
Em.$.AJAX( ... ).done().fail().always();
```

Is it best practice to cast the request into an Ember Promise? Should it *always* be cast?

```
Em.RSVP.Promise.cast( Ember.$.AJAX( ... ) ).then().catch().always();
```

NOTE: I've noticed when writing tests, that Ember will complain if it's not cast (bc it's not in the Ember Run loop), but my code still works when using the app even when not cast.  I find myself changing my code *only* so I can run tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to process the result in the Ember run loop (which I guess can be done by casting it to an RSVP Promise). If not, your app can become out of sync. That question is answered [in the Ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/understanding-ember/run-loop/#toc_what-happens-if-i-forget-to-start-a-run-loop-in-an-async-handler), as well as other questions regarding the run loop.